# ffmpeg - How to interpolate frames at a single instance in a video?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-editing

I have a 5 second video with 60 fps. It is a single take shot except a minor cut at 00:00:02.208. I have found some resources that use interpolation in the entire video in order to increase frame rate or do a slow motion. However, I just want to generate frames at only that particular instance by interpolation (using the preceding and succeeding frames) in order to make a smooth transition. Is there anyway I can do that ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What reasearch have you done and what have you tried to resolve the issue on your own?